# H1 is styled differently if inside article? Also, how to style multiple paragraphs inside a div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is better and more efficient for styling multiple paragraphs inside a div or semantic tag but each paragraph will have different styles? Also whenever i put an h1 inside the article like you see on my code,it is not the actual size of an h1 for some strange reason,anyone know why?

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49eyL256/1/)**

example:

```
<section>
    <article class="first_article">
        <h1>tio</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
        <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
        <a href=""><img src="contact-button.png" alt="contact_button" class="contact_button"></a>
        <img src="cupcake.png" alt="cupcake" class="cupcake">
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: What pseudo-classes are you referring to, and what are your criteria for “better”? And your question about `h1` is totally unrelated to the rest (and the title of the question) and should be asked separately, with a description of expected rendering and how the results differ from it.

Comment: Umm, add classes to the `p` tags?

Comment: I answered your second question but I'm not clear on the first part - "more efficient styling"? What do you mean?

Comment: You can use a little-known tool in Chrome called "devtools". Open it up with F12. Right click on the `h1` element and choose "Inspect element". See what CSS rules are being applied, from where. You might find, for example, that there is a rule for `.first_article h1` which is kicking in. Or that you have a syntax error in your CSS, or HTML. Or whatever. Anyway, you need to do the process called "debugging".

Comment: torazaburo, i heard it's not good practice to use classes for each p element since it makes code messy. If that was false then i will gladly use classes,just let me know.

Comment: Umm, that's what classes are designed for, to define and apply styles. Of course, if there is really some semantic meaning to the first `p` tag, then by all means use `first-of-type`. If it's just accidental that it's the first `p`, then if you use `first-of-type` or `nth-of-type(7)`, then you'll spend the rest of your life tweaking and updating your HTML and CSS; it's up to you.

Comment: You should post different questions separately. Editing the title to contain two questions is not the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

For styling different paragraphs differently check out [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) which allow you to identify individual elements by their place within the DOM tree.  So for example, one way to target the first `<p>` child element of `<article>` is to use:

```
article p:first-of-type { //first <p> that is child of <article>
    color: yellow;
}
```

or

```
p:nth-child(2) { //all p tags that are second child elements (the first <p> in your case)
    color: yellow;
}
```

Either of those will target the first `<p>` element in your case. **[JS Fiddle Demo for Q1](http://jsfiddle.net/49eyL256/3/)**

#### Question 2

Having an `<h1>` tag as a child of an `<article>` tag changes the element, it reduces the size and adds margin.

It is equivalent to the following CSS:

```
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
        -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
    }
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo for Q2](http://jsfiddle.net/su48ez2x/)**

Comment: first of type is one that works. if i use p:nth-child(2) it doesn't look for the 2nd paragraph for some reason.

Comment: Oops, looks like my fiddle link for Q1 was not correct. Check it out now.

Comment: It's not the 2nd paragraph, it's the `<p>` element that is a second child element.  In your case that's the first `<p>` tag since there's an `<h1>` that is the first child element.  The second paragraph would be `p:nth-child(3)`

Comment: I see, if i use classes for each <p> element instead will that be considered bad coding practices? I am trying to learn about stuff like that as i create some small projects.

Comment: I don't think it's bad coding practice.  It really depends on what you want to achieve.  If you have lots of `<article>` elements all with the same `<h1></h1><p></p>` structure and you want them all to look the same then using the CSS I am providing will work well because it targets desired elements easily.  If you have a lot of different HTML structures going on with little consistency then better to create classes.

Comment: This does not answer the “better and more efficient” question, and the part about `h1` rendering is partly speculative, partly misleading.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela you are welcome to provide your own answer - the comment here is not constructive.  I agree with you OP should have posted two separate questions.